# How to run a AdWords code within a loop but only show every 2 times it turns

Tags: php, wordpress, google-ads-api

I am running a loop for my archive blog post in WordPress. I would like to show an Ad from Adwords every 2 blog post.

I tried adding a counter within the loop, but I don't think I am using the correct code as I don't see the Ads appear at all on the page.

Here's my code:

```
<?php $sql="select * from bbs_fight_schedule order by id DESC";
$i=0; // variable for counter 
$res=mysql_query($sql);
while($ress=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
$sqlsn=mysql_query("select * from bbs_fighter_profiles where id='$ress[1]'");
$reesn=mysql_fetch_array($sqlsn);
$f1=$reesn[1];
$sqlsn1=mysql_query("select * from bbs_fighter_profiles where id='$ress[2]'");
$reesn1=mysql_fetch_array($sqlsn1);
$f2=$reesn1[1]; 
?>
<div id="sch_hold"> 
//Blog post Excerpt here
</div>

//Calling Google Ads Here            
<?php 
$i++;
if(!$i%2) {
echo '<div>Google Ad Code Here</div>';
}
?>

<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Comment: No wonder you are having problems, php sql html soup with added tables and no indenting. pretty much unreadable

Comment: @user574632 Unfortunately, I didn't create the website, I am just supposed to add the Google Ads code. It is quite the mess. I wanted to verify if my php was ok though. This is what I added, shouldn't this work?

$i++;
if(!$i%2) {
echo '<div>Google Ad Code Here</div>';
}

Comment: Ok, you have my sympathy, i'll take a look

Comment: or move increment: `if($i%2){//}$i++;`